# Syntax error with nested ifs

Tags: php, syntax-error

I have the following code, and php -l myfile.php prints out the following:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '{' in test.php on line 13

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in test.php on line 13

Errors parsing myfile.php
```

For testing i've copied the function into on own file to make sure, the error is really in this function. I've triple checked the code (and if I missed some stupid error, please apologize).

Code:

```
<?php
function getNewChannelValue($value, $bit, $flip, $alpha) {
        $max = 255;
        if ($alpha) {
                $max = 127;
        }
        if ($flip) {
                if ($bit && ($value % 2 == 0)) {
                        $value++;
                } else if (!$bit && ($value % 2 != 0)) {
                        $value++;
                }
        } else { //This is line 13
                if ($bit && ($value % 2 == 0)) {
                        $value--;
                } else if (!$bit && ($value % 2 != 0)) {
                        $value--;
                }
        }
        if ($value > $max && $bit) {
                $value = $max;
        }
        if ($value > $max && !$bit) {
                $value = $max - 1;
        }
        if ($value < 0 && $bit) {
                $value = 1;
        }
        if ($value < 0 && !$bit) {
                $value = 0;
        }
        return $value;
}
?>
```

Comment: There is no syntax error with the code in the question. Most likely that means typing an unprintable character instead of whitespace.

Comment: _This is really weird..._ just remove the space between `else` and `{` , it worked for me. Yeah , initially it had a syntax error.

Comment: I'm unable to replicate your results. `php -l` notes no syntax errors.

Comment: Removing the Space helped! I don't understand why, but... o.O
@Tom Walters i had the error on two different OS with different php versions, OS X v 5.5 and Raspbian 5.4.4-14+deb7u8...

Comment: For that many ifs,a switch would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I finally found the error:
I opened the file with a hex editor and I discovered a non ASCII-char at this place...
Removing the char and replacing it with 0x20 (Space) helped...
Seems that nano or something else made a mistake during writing. AD7six was right.

But this doesn't explain why Shankar Damodaran had the same issue.